# How to create automatic Refresh when Checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

I want to create automatic refresh when check box click. countdown timer running well but still no luck when I click the checkbox

this is my code. need help to review my code

```js
// COUNTDOWN METHOD.
window.setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if (counter >= 0) {
    var span;
    span = document.getElementById("cnt");
    span.innerHTML = counter;
  }
  if (counter === 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
  }

}, 1000);

window.setInterval('refresh()', 10000);

// REFRESH OR RELOAD PAGE.
function refresh() {
  window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"> This page will reload in <span id="cnt" style="color:red;">30</span> Seconds
```

Comment: This is JavaScript, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onclick` handler:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="refresh()">
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the html, call a function which should be getting executed on checkbox selection

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="checkboxClicked()"> This page will reload in <span id="cnt" style="color:red;">30</span> Seconds
```

> In javasccript function start the timer and call refresh after 30sec.

```
function checkboxClicked() {
//function gets called when the checkbox is clicked and the counter starts
let counter = 30
window.setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {

        var span;
        span = document.getElementById("cnt");
        span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {

        clearInterval(counter);
    }
}, 1000);
window.setInterval('refresh()', 30000);
}

// REFRESH OR RELOAD PAGE. 
function refresh() {
  window.location.reload();
}
```